# Meeting with wordpress' xmlrpc library python

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm just meeting with [wordpress_xmlrpc library for python](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Awesome documentation, red it all for future, but still can't catch, how to mark post for 1-2 categories by ids. It seems to easy, but not for me. I can't make a post in category. When I'm trying to declare a category it posts in all categoryies, else only in category with id = 1.

```
wp = Client('http://example.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php', 'admin', 'admin')
post = WordPressPost()

post.title = 'My post'
post.content = 'The best post ever.'
post.id = wp.call(posts.NewPost(post))
cats = wp.call(taxonomies.GetTerms('category', 2))
post.terms = cats
post.post_status = 'publish'

wp.call(posts.EditPost(post.id, post))
```

In this code example is category id `2`, also I declared it like `(2)` and `[2]`, tryed many categoryes `(2, 4)`, `[2, 4]`. No difference.

Ofcourse there are categories with such ids, no mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sorted out.
`wp.call(taxonomies.GetTerms('category'))` as I tried firstly, get a list of avalible taxonomies objects.
To mark post in some category:

```
category_id = 3
cat = wp.call(taxonomies.GetTerm('category', category_id))
post.terms.append(cat)
```

If is needed to mark the post in 2+ categories, best way is to append them separetaly from each other, because post.terms is a list.